# Get usb device on provisioning from user input in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I build a vagrant file with a provisioning script. The goal ist to build a complete linux system  for a embedded device inside the vm and write it to a sdcard in the hosts memory card reader. I would like to ask the user for the device with the sdcard. 
I know i could just write a image back to the shared vagrant folder. But i would like to have a solution i could just run vagrant up, go for lunch and have the sdcard ready when i get back. 
Anybody got an idea ? Would be nice if it would be a real cross platform solution.

Comment: If your sdcard reader is connected via USB, you can share usb with the virtual machine and thus write to the sdcard from inside the vm.

Comment: Yes that's what i am doing right now. What i would like to have is a prompt which asks the user something like "You got these usb drives 1,2 ... Which one do you want to mount in the vagrant vm". Then the provision script will run and write the system image to the choosen sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the hostusb devices using vboxmanage and the Vagrantfile is just ruby, so you could probably do a shell call within the Vagrantfile to get the devices and then evaluate the user selected device and put the USB device ID in the virtualbox syntax as additional arguments that get lazy loaded before the actual vagrant portion of the Vagrantfile runs.